# PBKDF2 result is different in CryptoJS and iOS

Tags: ios, cryptojs

PBKDF2 result is different in CryptoJS and iOS.

Here is my code

CryptoJS

```
var key= CryptoJS.PBKDF2("gf8uny", "2mnfpLsa+5I=", { keySize: 256/32, iterations: 1000 });
console.log(key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
// console output ANepH98DqZHtMkkVrIk/CNmfykVPfEFpoax2PF8z5k8=
```

iOS

```
NSMutableData *key = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:kCCKeySizeAES256];

NSString *password = @"gf8uny";
NSData*salt =[NSData dataFromBase64String:@"2mnfpLsa+5I="];

int result = CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2,         // algorithm
                                  password.UTF8String,                // password
                                  password.length,                    // passwordLength
                                  salt.bytes,                         // salt
                                  salt.length,                        // saltLen
                                  kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1,                              // PRF
                                  1000,                 // rounds
                                  key.mutableBytes,            // derivedKey
                                  key.length);                 // derivedKeyLen

NSString *sKey= [key base64EncodedString];
NSLog(@"key%@", sKey);
// output AjHjVAwHCpF1SnNDN6ri9ms7ig88VFBPwRVRMppBgnU=
```

Can someone help? what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript version of your code, the salt should be a WordArray object not a javascript string. Basically in your two examples, the salts are different and therefore you are getting two different results.

To verify what I am talking about, try the following piece of code in the browser javascript console:

```
saltWArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
saltString = saltWArray.toString(); // same salt but in String format

var key1 = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("password", saltWArray, { keySize: 512/32, iterations: 300 });
var key2 = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("password", saltString, { keySize: 512/32, iterations: 300 });
```

In the above code, key1 and key2 will be different, because the salts are inherently different even though the salt content is the same.